# Recursively remove entire directory with files in Dart?

Tags: dart

How do you recursively remove an entire directory in Dart along with all the files?

For example:

```
/path/to/project/foo.dart
/path/to/project/remove/all/of/these
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

It's easier than it sounds.

If I understood you right, it would go like this:

```dart
import 'dart:io';

main() {
  // Deletes the directory "remove" with all folders and files under it.
  new Directory('remove').delete(recursive: true);
}
```